# Algorithm to arrange tooltips arround a complex shape

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I need to arrange tooltips for points that are located on a complex 2D shape.

- The tooltips have different sizes
- They must not obscure the shape itself
- The lines that connect the tooltip to the points should not cross one each other.
- The tooltip should be as mush closer to the point it belongs to.

[image]

I've tried several searches in google but nothing was close enough to what I need.

Comment: If you want to have a generic solution it will not be that easy. I can suggest force-based graph layouting algorithms (of course they should be modified for your needs).

Answer (score 0):

You've asked quite a doozy. I haven't personally worked on something like this, another SO member will likely be able to give you a complete solution. However, here are some points to consider when finding your solution.

## 1. The tooltips have different sizes

You will need a way determining this independently of your shape location algorythm. Performing the re-size as part of step 2 would make things much more complicated and may result in inconsistent behavior. So firstly, look into generating the dimensions of your tooltips.

## 2. They must not obscure the shape itself

In principle, you want a solution where the tooltip is not 'colliding' 'inside' the complex shape. Looking up '2d shape collision detection' would help here. You will need to know the dimensions of the shape of interest. You can't use a picture of a shape (unless you use a map of some sort). Most algorythms will require the following information for shapes containing concave points:

- The points (2d vectors) that make up the complex shape
- The points from which tooltips "spawn"
- The tooltip dimensions (see point 1)

## 3. The lines that that connect the tooltip to a point should not cross eachover

This makes the problem significantly more complicated because it implies that multiple tooltips generated by #2 may be visible at the same time which will introduce alot of complexity.

Now you have N tooltips which need N locations occupying different areas which may not overlap, collide with the complex shape, or, when a line is drawn from them to point x, does not intersect any other lines from the remaining (N-1) shapes. It means the algorthm must be performed on the entire set and find the correct locations for all of them, a kind of three body problem.

## 4. The tooltip must be as close as possible to its associated point

This adds another small caveat which, because of stipulations set in #3 may not be able to be met 'ideally' (what if two shapes are colliding near two close points, which one 'wins out'?).

Again, these are some points to consider as you generate a solution. The result is that you have mathematically 'ideal' locations for your tooltips. However, with these considerations in mind, you may want to look into where realistic concessions may be made. If it's for a design project where the complex shape is unlikely to change then semimanual solutions may be better. If it's for a complex piece of software that will require automatically generated locations you may be able to redesign the UI to give the user the necessary feedback without such a complex solution.

Answer (score 0):

A heuristic:

1. Compute the centroid of the points.
2. Place a circle, centered at the centroid, fully enclosing the shape.
3. Find the places on the circle, where a line form the center through each point
   intersects the circle, i.e. project the points on the the circle.
4. These locations would serve as corners for the tooltip, depending on the which quadrant the point on the circle is, relative to the circle center.
5. You may increase the circle radius a bit, for aesthetic purposes :)

If I'm not mistaken, this should cover requirements (1), (2) and (3). For (4) you can refine the initial place by moving the tooltip towards the sphere center and checking for intersection with the shape, e.g. using binary search.

Something like this:

[image]

There are problems with this approach, of course, but nevertheless it may turn out to be a good starting point for refinement :)